# Parsing encapsulated Signed Data

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle

I am encapsulating EnvelopedData in SignedData and then in EnvelopedData. 
encrypt->sign->encrypt . However when i decrypt the message and create CMSSingedData out of decrypted content i get an error:

```
   org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSException: IOException reading content. 
    at org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSUtils.readContentInfo(Unknown Source) 
   Caused by: java.io.IOException: DER length more than 4 bytes: 98 
    at org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.readLength(Unknown Source)
```

Here is the code, where i create the EnvelopedData :

```
CMSSignedDataStreamGenerator signedGenerator; 
    CMSEnvelopedDataStreamGenerator envelopedGenerator; 
    try { 
        signedGenerator = getCMSSignedDataStreamGenerator(builder); 
        envelopedGenerator = getCMSEnvelopedDataStreamGenerator(builder); 
OutputStream envelopedStream2 = envelopedGenerator.open(CMSObjectIdentifiers.signedData,out,settings.getEncryptor()); 
        OutputStream signingStream = signedGenerator.open(CMSObjectIdentifiers.envelopedData,envelopedStream2,encapsulate); 
        OutputStream envelopedStream1 =  envelopedGenerator.open(signingStream,settings.getEncryptor()); 
        content.writeTo(envelopedStream1); 
        envelopedStream1.close(); 
        signingStream.close(); 
        envelopedStream2.close(); 


    }catch (CMSException e){ 
        throw new IOException(e.toString()); 

    }catch (MessagingException e) { 
        throw new IOException(e.toString()); 

    }
```

Here is my test :

```
@Test 
public  void testEncryptSignEncrypt() throws  Exception{ 


  Properties props = System.getProperties(); 
  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null); 
  RecipientId recId = new JceKeyTransRecipientId(cert); 
  MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session, new FileInputStream("EncryptSignEncryptPCKS7")); 
  SMIMEEnveloped m = new SMIMEEnveloped(msg); 
  ContentInfo contentInfo = m.toASN1Structure(); 
  EnvelopedData envData = EnvelopedData.getInstance(contentInfo.getContent()); 

 System.out.println("The content of enveloped data " + envData.getEncryptedContentInfo().getContentType()); 

  assertEquals(CMSObjectIdentifiers.signedData,  envData.getEncryptedContentInfo().getContentType(), "The content of enveloped data, should be SignedData"); 

  byte[] cont = decrypt(smimeKey,m,cert); 


  CMSSignedData signedData = new CMSSignedData(cont); 


  assertEquals(CMSObjectIdentifiers.envelopedData.toString(),  signedData.getSignedContentTypeOID(), "The content of signed data, should be enveloped data"); 


  assertEquals(true, verify(signedData), "the message was altered!");
```

}

```
private static byte[] decrypt(SmimeKey key, CMSEnvelopedData envelopedData, X509Certificate cert) throws CMSException{ 

    RecipientId recId = new JceKeyTransRecipientId(cert); 
    RecipientInformationStore recipients = envelopedData.getRecipientInfos(); 
    RecipientInformation recipient = recipients.get(recId); 
    byte[]  cont = recipient.getContent(new JceKeyTransEnvelopedRecipient(smimeKey.getPrivateKey()).setProvider("BC")); 

    return cont; 
}
```

Comment: Although you've provided a lot of code, this isn't an MCVE, which means we would be guessing. E.g. you could be using the wrong stream as output of the encryption function. You should also take a look at the data returned from your decrypt function before verifying the embedded signed data structure within it.

Comment: thank you. I have tests for encrypt -> sign and sign->encrypt, where i decrypt and verify signatures.  Everything works fine but with sign->encrypt-> sign and encrypt->sign->encrypt i get errors.